# Do people tend to be more hostile toward users with default gravatars?

Tags: discussion, gravatar, behavior, profile-picture

When I signed up, I encountered some hostility, but it seems to have gone down since I added a personalized image. Do people on here tend to be more hostile toward users who have a default gravatar?

Comment: When who doesn't have one?

Comment: When you just signed up and you don't have one on here. Initially the hostility was higher, it seems to have gone down after I put up an image on my profile.

Comment: Are we talking about people being hostile _toward you_ until _you_ obtained an avatar?

Comment: You mean when you have a default gravatar, rather than something else?  I've never experienced any hostility on any site where I've been a member

Comment: How does this question differ from [that one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24838/are-you-less-likely-to-down-vote-someone-whose-gravatar-is-a-photograph-of-them)?

Comment: @Louis it's not different but if we choose to close as dupe now this question here will be closed as "Not clear what you're asking". (technical reasons)

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think so. There are plenty of regular users on various sites I've used who still use the default avatar, and they don't cop hostility just because of that.

You may be mistaking correlation for causation: you might have changed your profile picture *around the same time* something else changed. Your behaviour might have changed, for instance, or you've simply been interacting with people who are being less hostile.

Ultimately, it's your behaviour that determines peoples' hostility or lack thereof. If you have 1 rep and the default avatar or you're totally new, you'll receive respect if you're engaging with people constructive. If you notice correlation between those factors and hostility, it probably isn't because they have 1 rep and the default answer - it might be because the person is new to the community, unaware of how it works, and grating against the expectations of the members of the community. The fact they have only 1 rep and the default avatar is an incidental and unimportant detail compared to their behaviour.

Comment: Is there generally more hostility when someone has low rep points?

Comment: Probably not, see the last paragraph.